# Do more people today speak Latin or Esperanto? Are there any native speakers of Latin, like there are hundreds of native speakers of Esperanto?

Tags: contemporary-latin

Do more people today speak Latin or Esperanto? Are you aware of any estimates?

Also, are there any native speakers of Latin, like there are hundreds of native speakers of Esperanto?

Comment: I googled this last year, and I saw that around 2,000 people speak latin fluently and 10,000 speak speranto. I don't know if there are natives of latin nowadays.